# Android cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, class

Alright so before you go and start stating, go look around as your title matches many questions asked here. And in that case, you're correct, but... Every single thing I've tried on these asked questions didn't help me at all.

So I'm actually trying to build an RssFeed application for Android devices (Still Learning).
My problem comes in the MainActivity, mind you. All my classes, xmls, and other content are properly coded with no issues or errors. People are saying that you should get rid of the imports that contain "android.r" and I've looked throught and haven't found any imports that contain the said quotation.

My MainActivity code:

```
package com.ascendapps.licknriff;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.ascendapps.licknriff.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        try {

            RssReader rssReader = new RssReader("http://www.licknriff.com/feed/");
            ListView Items = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            // create a list adapter
            ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this.android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, RssReader.getItems());
            // --
            Items.setAdapter(adapter);
            // --
            Items.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(RssReader.getItems(), this));     }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("SimpleRssReader", e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `this.android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this.android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, RssReader.getItems());
```

to this:

```
ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, RssReader.getItems());
```

`this` should be passed as context in constructor of ArrayAdapter class.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this.android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, RssReader.getItems());
```

with

```
ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, RssReader.getItems());
```

`android` is the namespace of the Android `R` class. It doesn't belong to your activity class.

The first parameter is of `Context` type, so you activity is a suitable parameter as it inherits from `Context`.

Comment: `this` must be passed as context. Check ArrayAdapter constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You have a full-stop, but you need a comma,  after `this` here -

```
// ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(
//     this.android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, RssReader.getItems());
ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(
    this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, RssReader.getItems());
```

Comment: `this` must be passed as context. Check ArrayAdapter constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have typo error. While writing code, you simply type `.` ( dot ) instead of ',' ( comma ). Just replace `.` with `,` after `this` like below,

```
ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, RssReader.getItems());
```